# node.js | BAD_REQUEST error suddenly appeared

Tags: node.js, bad-request

I use node.js with the [google-translate-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-translate-api) package.

It all worked fine for months but suddenly and I can't tell why, the simple code

```
translate("hello", {from: "en", to: "fr"}).then(res => {
    console.log(res.text);
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

stopped working and I get this error everytime now :

> Error at C:\Users\...\AutoTranslate\node_modules\google-translate-api\index.js:105:17 at  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7) code: 'BAD_REQUEST'

Therefore it is not due to my code but probably to some parameters of node but I don't know. From now on, other packages which use async calls crash with the same error.

I even tried to uninstall node and reinstall it but I can't make it to work again.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe an update to the library, or the translation API itself?

Comment: But other packages don't work either anymore. I have node.js on my phone and it keeps working (it runs a discord bot which can translates) but whenever I use it on my computer now it crashes with BAD_REQUEST.

Comment: Have you tried looking into the package's index.js? Maybe checking GitHub for issues?

Comment: I didn't but as I said it's probably not the package, other packages doesn't work either and this particular package does work on my phone. I will try tomorrow because my computer is already turned off for today.

Comment: Ok, it seems to be mentionned on the github errors, but sadly not solved. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Ip has been blocked so try to connect with other network it will work fine

Comment: I've used another google translate trick so it's not a problem anymore, thanks anyway!

Comment: @QuentinJanuel.. what have you used??

Comment: Ah I'm so sorry but I didn't recall at all, I think I just changed of package but I don't even have my code anymore.

Comment: @QuentinJanuel I am facing a similar problem. can you give me a solution?